# How do we loop through JSON from SAUCE_ONDEMAND_BROWSERS in a Robot Framework script

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, jenkins-plugins, robotframework, saucelabs

I am using the latest Sauce OnDemand Plugin to get the Desired capabilities for Robot Framework Script.

[image: example image with three OS and browser selections on Sauce OnDemand Jenkins Plugin]

Because I am selecting multiple OS and Browser combinations, I will get the values stored in `SAUCE_ONDEMAND_BROWSERS` which is a Json. The Values for JSON should be added to the desired capabilities.

How do I loop through a JSON and assign the values to variables such that the selenium test is run through all selected combinations from the Sauce OnDemand Plugin?

The following works, when I just have a single operating system/browser combination.
`${desired_capabilities} build:%{JENKINS_BUILD_NUMBER},name:%{JENKINS_BUILD_NUMBER}, platform:%{SELENIUM_PLATFORM},browserName:%{SELENIUM_BROWSER‌​},version:%{SELENIUM‌​_VERSION},tunnelIden‌​tifier:%{TUNNEL_IDEN‌​TIFIER}`

The Sauce plugin has set the following environment variables:
`SELENIUM_DRIVER: sauce-ondemand:?os=Linux&browser=chrome&browser-version=latest&username=g246877&access-key=86c9e0cc-4567-46g2-9b6l-ufeyda3621b16
SAUCE_ONDEMAND_BROWSERS: [{"os":"Linux","platform":"LINUX","browser":"chrome","browser-version":"latest","long-name":"Google Chrome","long-version":"latest","url":"sauce-ondemand:?os=Linux&browser=chrome&browser-version=latest&username=g246877&access-key=86c9e0cc-4567-46g2-9b6l-ufeyda3621b16"},{"os":"Linux","platform":"LINUX","browser":"opera","browser-version":"latest","long-name":"Opera","long-version":"latest","url":"sauce-ondemand:?os=Linux&browser=opera&browser-version=latest&username=g246877&access-key=86c9e0cc-4567-46g2-9b6l-ufeyda3621b16"},{"os":"Windows 10","platform":"WIN10","browser":"chrome","browser-version":"latest","long-name":"Google Chrome","long-version":"latest","url":"sauce-ondemand:?os=Windows 10&browser=chrome&browser-version=latest&username=g246877&access-key=86c9e0cc-4567-46g2-9b6l-ufeyda3621b16"},{"os":"Windows 2008","platform":"VISTA","browser":"firefox","browser-version":"latest","long-name":"Firefox","long-version":"latest","url":"sauce-ondemand:?os=Windows 2008&browser=firefox&browser-version=latest&username=g246877&access-key=86c9e0cc-4567-46g2-9b6l-ufeyda3621b16"}]`

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

`SAUCE_ONDEMAND_BROWSERS` is json.

Here is what does the magic:

1. Save the Json as a file
2. Use the `Get Json Value` to get the values of each variable.
3. Use the `Set Variable` to append each to get the desired capabilities.
4. Pass it to the `Open Browser` keyword in the same `FOR` loop.